# Sorting array to get specified element at index 0 of it

Tags: java, collections

I have a String array say

```
String [] my_array_list = { "SOMETHING1" , "SOMETHING2" , "ALCHOHAL", 
                        "SOMETHING3" , "ALL", "SOMETHING4" };
```

Now when I apply sorting on this say `Arrays.sort( my_array_list );`

Then I get output like that:

```
ALCHOHAL
ALL
SOMETHING1
SOMETHING2 ... etc.
```

Now here's my point. 
What we need to do if I need `"ALL"` at index 0 of String array. i.e always need `"ALL"` at    first position of String array before I move out.

Is there any way in sorting method or we need to do some thing else for that.

Comment: then put it inside the array after the sort

Comment: Do you want a particular element at the start of array after sorting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elegant approach is to define a `Comparator` that favours your `"ALL"` string above all others:

```
Arrays.sort(my_array_list, new Comparator<String>() {

  private static final String FIRST = "ALL";

  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (o1.equals(FIRST)) {
      return -1;
    } else if (o2.equals(FIRST)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
  }
});
```

You may wish to  refactor this anonymous `Comparator` into a top-level class if you have lots of similar sorting to do. It would be trivial to add a constructor that takes the "magic" word and ensures it comes first in the sort.

Comment: I was just about to add this suggestion to my answer when you posted. : / This is probably the best solution if the OP wants to program something in.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for your reply. Your approach is best just like Maroun.

Comment: Beautiful answer. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Here what you can do:

1. Remove `all` from the array.
2. Sort it.
3. Convert to to [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).
4. [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) `all` at index 0.
5. [Convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) it back to array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me perform this stuff. Will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a prefix to `"ALL"` so it is lexicographically always at the beginning. A space precedes all characters so you can just name it `" ALL"` or something like `"_ALL"`. If that won't do you have to remove it from the array somehow when it sorts or implement a custom comparator that accounts for the special case.

Comment: Really a good one. I used this stuff. But we should always go for some better approach whose probability for exception is less. Overall Thanks.

Comment: @AndroidHacker I'm slightly surprised you accepted this answer. Is this really the best approach?

Comment: @Duncan Nope this isn't best approach but this suits my requirement as I need not to deal with any sort of exception.

Comment: @Duncan I guess it depends on what the OP is actually using it for. If the array were not known ahead of time, like if it were some kind of input a custom comparator would definitely be the way to go. Otherwise just appending an underscore is certainly the simplest.

Comment: @AndroidHacker What sort of exception are you referring to?

Comment: @Ducon IM new in development. I try thing and then go for that. Right by time IM going on for your suggestion as many of them suggest to do so.